# Exported Jar file won't read file inside jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

In the code sample below, when I test the code in Eclipse it works just fine. However, when I export the jar file and test it via the command line, it throws an error: `IIOException: Can't read input file!`

```
private BufferedImage img = null;
private String imgSource;

if (img == null)
{
    try {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("Images/questionMark.png");
        System.out.println(url.getPath()); 
        /* This prints: file:/C:/Users/Keno/Documents/javaFile.jar!/javaFile/Images/questionMark.png */
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        img = ImageIO.read(file);
        imgSource = file.getName();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file I want to get is located inside the Images folder which is inside the `javaFile` package. I've noticed one thing that may indicate the problem.

1. In the print statement I have, I notice an exclamation sign at the end of the javaFile.jar section. Is that correct? Could that indicate an issue with the file or structure?

---

Also, just in case someone has a better suggestion as to how I should load the file, I'll tell you my intentions. I would like to load the file from a relative location (Images folder) in the jar. I would like to display it (Already done in my actual code) and also store the location to be passed later on to another function (also done).

Comment: try with getClass().getResourceAsStream

Comment: @oliv37 That would mean I'd have to turn url into an InputStream. Would I then need to convert it to a File?

Comment: ImageIO.read(inputStream)

Comment: @oliv37 Awesome it worked! I'm going to test a few other things and verify that this will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public void test() {
    try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Images/questionMark.png")) {
        ImageIO.read(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it worked, but my only concern is that using the InputStream seemed to be a little slower than reading from a file. Is there any way to speed it up or something?

Comment: I don't think it's slower than calling read method with file argument. If you look at the source code of the read method -> http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#ImageIO.read%28java.io.File%29 you will see that it create an inputStream.

Comment: Oh that probably means something else in my code seems to be slowing it down. I know what the issue is now then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check if your class is in the same directory than Images inside your jar.

```
   |
   |- Your class
   |- Images
       |- questionMark.png
```

Also, have you tried using directly your url object ?

```
File file = new File(url);
```

Comment: You can't make a file from a url object.

Comment: My mistake, I meant URI not URL