# Java + Eclipse SWT project, trying to get folder path into the "jar"

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm developing a project in Eclipse with SWT, where the interface is shown in a browser and for that, I use the XULRunner (Firefox) instead of using the standard browser.

I thought to compile the jar with the xurlrunner folder inside, so I created a source folder called "plugins" and copied the xurlrunner folder inside and got the path:

```java
URL xulrunner = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xulrunner");
File file = new File(xulrunner.toURI());
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType", "mozilla");
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", 
        -> file.getAbsolutePath());
```

It worked, but only when run from within the Eclipse before exporting, however, the big problem is that when I export for a jar executable, the JVM can not load, of course, the reason is that `file.getAbsolutePath()` could not point to into the jar.

For images, I use `getResourceAsStream()` and it works very well once compiled, but when it is to transform a folder path inside the jar to String is that it is difficult.

QUESTION:

Is there any other way I can point to a folder into the jar that can be turned to String?

---

PROPOSAL

if there is no a way to keep the xurlrunner folder into the jar, I'll create an installer apart to extract it from a zip to the same location of the program installation and dynamically point to it.

Comment: You may benefit from checking out these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182101/exported-jar-file-wont-read-file-inside-jar | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269693/unable-to-locate-open-image-inside-exported-jar

Comment: @KenoClayton   System.setProperty() only accepts String, how can I pass "InputStream getResourceAsStream" to it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test

Comment: Use `IOUtils.toString()`

Comment: @KenoClayton Scanner instead of IOUtils.toString, Scanner scanner = new Scanner(InputStream); scanner.useDelimiter("\\A"); String str = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : null; but is not my case, thank u so much, I think the way is extract xurlrunner into my program installation path and point to it.

Answer (score 0):

SWT expects the `XULRunnerPath` to point to a regular filesystem folder. Thefore the entire xulrunner folder must be extracted into a regular folder before setting the system property.