# How to add relative path to my script file in java?

Tags: java, sql, relative-path

I have a directory structure as follows:

Service
|
src
|
com.abc.SaaSPlugin
|
myDb.sql

How can I get the relative path so that I can read the sql file and run the script.

Comment: Check this out, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182101/exported-jar-file-wont-read-file-inside-jar/36182958#36182958

Comment: As per my directory structure can you give me the path written in String ? @KenoClayton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
String absPath = new File("src/com/abc/SaaSPlugin/myDb.sql").getAbsolutePath();
```

You could also move the file to a different folder for ease of use i.e.

```
project
  -- Resources
  --src
    --abc ......
```

Put the myDb.sql in resources folder and then code will be..

```
String absPath = new File("Resources/myDb.sql").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JacquesRamsden